# selecting a row with a lower value in one column SQL

Tags: sql, select

i have two rows:

```
ID | Name
1  | Adrian
2  | Cheska
```

I want to be able to select the row with a lower id, which in this case is 'Adrian' because he has the ID=1 which is lower than 2. How can i select the row with a lower column value?

Comment: How many rows do you want, just one? Lower than what? Since you've provided a simplified example, what if there are multiple IDs that are lower than X? Is X a parameter or do you want the rcord with the lowest ID? Btw, what RDBMS are you using? [-1 for too many open questions]

Comment: So `@Name='Adrian'` is a parameter and you want to find next record with a lower ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about your RDBMS..This should work in all RDBMSs

```
select * 
from your_table
where ID in(select min(id) from your_table)
```

or

**EDIT:**(as per  **a_horse_with_no_name**'s  comment)

```
select * 
from your_table
where ID =(select min(id) from your_table)
```

Comment: `where id = (...)` would also work. `IN` is not needed as the sub-select will only return a single value due to the aggregate function.

Comment: if ID is your primary key, I think Shakir's answer is best, if not, I would recommend Joe's. Cos select top 1 will neglect similar result. For example 1 | Adrian  1 | Jessie 2 | Cheska then  1 | Jessie will be neglected

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Good point..but I guess that may not work in some databases

Comment: Why ID in (SELECT min(id) from your_table),
when it could be ID=(SELECT min(id) from your_table)
as Min(ID) will always be a single row!!

Can you explain?

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR: Good point..but I guess that may not work in some databases

Comment: OP want to _select the row_ which is singular. ID is also probably a parameter since he mentions the "Adrian-row" as starting point.

Comment: using `id = (...)` works in all DBMS - as long as the sub-select indeed only returns a single row and column.

Comment: @Larry Here's one another solution, if ID is not the primary key,

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM <tablename>
ORDER BY ID ASC

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR: that (with ties...) only works in SQL Server. We don't know the DBMS in use yet.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Just, for thought process, do we have an alternate for databases that dont use WITH TIES ?? What alternate do we have??

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR: either the solution posted by Joe or windowing functions (`row_number()`, `dense_rank()` ...) which are ANSI standard and supported by most modern DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <tablename>
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE something = somethingElse ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table_name d where d.id = (select min(id) from table_name);`